# Android layout positioning. Two rows text

Tags: android, layout

I've got some problem with positioning `TextViews`. Currently my layout looks like:

```
Text1: Text2
Text3: Text4
```

Ok, but when `Text2` has 2 rows length or more I've got:

```
Text1: Text2:1
Text3: Text2:2/Text4
```

I don't know how to set up my layout to obtain view like:

```
Text1: Text2:1
       Text2:2
Text3: Text4
```

Can somebody help me solve that problem?

XML code:

```
(...)
//Text1:
<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/tv_author_label"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tv_genre_label"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/img_Cover"
    android:text="Author: "
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

//Text2:
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_author"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/tv_author_label"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/tv_author_label"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tv_author_label"
    android:text="Anonymous Anonymous"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

//Text3:
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_availability_label"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tv_author_label"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/img_Cover"
    android:
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:text="Availability: "
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

//Text4:
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_availability"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/tv_availability_label"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/tv_availability_label"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tv_availability_label"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="@+id/tv_availability_label"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tv_author"
    android:text="b/d"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

(...)
```

Comment: Have you tried using a table layout?

Answer (score 0):

you can reconstruct your code something like this,

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="dfsdjfkd dsfsdf sdfsdf sdfsdfsd fjlsdjf sdj; j; jlksdfjl sdjflkdsjflsdk jkldsjf lsjldkfj sdl" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I hope it will be helpful !!

Answer (score 0):

You can encapsulate the row of text views inside a linear layout with orientation - horiontal